# I am not able to login to my wp-admin panel

Tags: login

I changed my Wordpress folder name in htdocs as localhost/ecom/  and now when I try to access localhost/ecom/wp-admin/ it shows page not found

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `wp-config.php` before line

```
  /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

and check if it works.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/ecom' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/ecom' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is always better to change the URLs in wp-options table, rather changing the wp-config.php entries.

See this entry in the Codex  https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL where it says

> This is not necessarily the best fix, it's just hardcoding the values
>   into the site itself. You won't be able to edit them on the General
>   settings page anymore when using this method.

So, although changing the values in wp-config.php will work (and is often stated as an 'answer'), I think that the more correct way is to set the proper URLs in the wp-options table.